# Display XML children in HTML tabs

Tags: javascript, xml

I am trying to display data from an XML code like this:

```
<escrutinio_sitio>
    <resultados>
       <numero_partidos>4</numero_partidos>

    <partido>
        <nombre>IU</nombre>
        <electos>2</electos>
        <electo1>AMADEU SANCHIS I LABIÓS</electo1>
        <electo2>ROSA ALBERT BERLANGA</electo2>
        <votos_numero>28489</votos_numero>
        <votos_porciento>7,17</votos_porciento>
    </partido>

    <partido>
        <nombre>COMPROMÍS-Q</nombre>
        <electos>3</electos>
        <electo1>JOAN RIBÓ CANUT</electo1>
        <electo2>CONSOL CASTILLO PLAZA</electo2>
        <electo3>MARIA PILAR SORIANO RODRIGUEZ</electo3>
        <votos_numero>35881</votos_numero>
        <votos_porciento>9,03</votos_porciento>
    </partido>

</resultados>

</escrutinio_sitio>
```

for doing so, I have this JavaScript code which tries to obtain the `nombre` tag value into the title of different tabs, but it does not work as it should.

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","resultadosval.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<ul class="nav nav-tabs">");
var branch = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName("partido");
for(i=0;i<branch.length;i++) {
    subbranch = branch[i].childNodes ;
    for(j=0;j<subbrach.length;j++) {
        if (subbranch[j].nodeName=="nombre" ){
        document.write("<li class="active"><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="tab">");
        document.write(subbranch[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</a></li>");}
    }
            }
document.write("</ul>");
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Observe the quotation marks "" and ''.. Please note that you had string breaks which throws the errors and script execution breaks. Due to which you seem to have a problem

```
<script>
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","resultadosval.xml",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

document.write("<ul class='nav nav-tabs'>");
var branch = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName("partido");
for(i=0;i<branch.length;i++) {
    subbranch = branch[i].childNodes ;
    for(j=0;j<subbrach.length;j++) {
        if (subbranch[j].nodeName=="nombre" ){
        document.write("<li class='active'><a href='#tab_a' data-toggle='tab'>");
        document.write(subbranch[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</a></li>");}
    }
            }
document.write("</ul>");
</script>
```